# How to create a SQL Server database on production server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm working on an Angular / .Net core project, and I want to deploy it on my homemade server equipped with Windows Server 2016.

I'm stuck at figuring out the best way to create my database from my migrations files. I've seen some topics on stackoverflow about it, but I don't want to make mistakes on my server, so I'm asking for the best way to do that.

The first option I think is to install Visual Studio IDE on my server. Then I can open my project and run an `Update-database` command, which will read all migrations files and create database.

But I don't think I'm supposed to install Visual Studio on a server...

The second option is something I saw on StackOverflow. In my development environment, I can use the command `dotnet ef migrations script`, which will generate a script.

But I'm not sure where I should put this script. I think probably in Microsoft SQL Server Management studio, New query and put my script.

Could you please tell me the best way ?

Answer (score 1):

you need dotnet sdk in order to use `dotnet ef migrations script` but you can use your development pc to connect to your remote SQL Server and do migrations. for this, just point your connection string to remote SQL Server and use either `Update-Database` or `dotnet ef update database`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution exists and You can use SQL server **Generate Script** to query all your database objects and  execute it on target SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do "first create" of your database in production environment is to **Generate Script** from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and run that script on production Db server. The reason of that is because your database is empty (you can put all of data in script) and you can easily change the name, etc.

After that, on new versions of your application, the best way is to use `Update-Database -Script` and save/add that script to your deployment scripts.
When you are preparing for go-live, try that scripts with **ROLLBACK TRANSACTION**, if something fails...